# Getting the wrong input with BufferedReader Class

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm trying to use the BufferedReader class and I'm getting a weird output compared to what I put in.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class A1TCPClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
    System.out.println("Enter an integer 1, 2, or 3: ");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); //This basically like creating scanner class 
    int choice = br.read();
    br.close();

    System.out.println(choice);

}
```

This produces the output

```
Enter an integer 1, 2, or 3: 
3          
51
```

With that I'll say 2 produces 50 and 1 produces 49... What went wrong here?

Comment: Note that `BufferedReader#read()` reads a single **character** as an `int`. You're seeing the codepoint for `3`, `2`, and `1`, respectively. Using `System.out.println((char) choice)` will give you the expected output, but that likely won't help with the rest of your program when you write it. You need to parse the character into an integer. Personally, I would do this with `BufferedReader#readLine()` and process the returned `String`. Or use `Scanner` and its `nextInt()` method.

Comment: Every text character has a numeric code (codepoint) associated with it.  The first 128 codepoints are called [ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com).  Look up the values you’re getting (49, 50, 51) under the ‘Dec’ columns in that table.  (Dec stands for decimal, which means base 10 numbers.  Hx means hexadecimal, which is base 16, and Oct means octal, which is base 8.)  When you find the row where the Dec value is 49, 50, or 51, look rightward:  what character (under the ‘Chr’ column) corresponds to each of those values?

Comment: @Slaw, If your comment were an answer, I'd upvote.

Comment: @Mike I found some duplicates instead